# hide the ECB menu item for particular library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I want to hide the "View Item" menu item from ECB menu for particular library in Sharepoint 2010. Please give me suggestion to do this.

Comment: Can you explain what motivates this requirement? Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following links to get an idea about hiding an item in ECB.

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768565(v=office.14).aspx
2. http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/customize-sharepoint-library-menu-items-91509.aspx
3. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dipper/archive/2006/10/05/how-to-remove-or-hiding-items-in-list-toolbar-in-sharepoint-server-2007.aspx.

Using javascript,

1. http://weblogs.asp.net/peterbrunone/archive/2012/05/10/hiding-buttons-on-the-ecb.aspx

Comment: As of Nov 2014, the extreme-sharepoint.com site is expired and gets you a generic GoDaddy parking page.